# Diamond Distribution in system K (Garson Modal Logic exercise 1.8)

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, modal-logic

I want to prove $\Diamond (P \lor Q) \Rightarrow \Diamond P \lor \Diamond Q$
It was a biconditional, but I have proved the other one. Thanks for the answer. Please use Garson's method. Thanks. I am stuck on this, any help. Please.

I don't have any work to show for it because I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try proof by contradiction

Here is one possible approach
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
\begin{align}
\fitch{\Diamond(p\lor q)}{
\neg\square\neg(p\lor q)\hspace{7.8ex}\Diamond\text{Def}\\
\fitch{\neg(\Diamond p\lor\Diamond q)}
{\neg\Diamond p\land\neg\Diamond q\hspace{5ex}\text{DM}\\
\neg\Diamond p\hspace{12ex}\&\text{Out}\\
\fitch{\neg\square\neg p}{\Diamond p\hspace{10ex}\Diamond\text{Def}\\
\bot\hspace{11ex}\bot\text{In}}\\\square \neg p\hspace{13.5ex}\text{IP}\\
\neg\Diamond q\hspace{12ex}\&\text{Out}\\
\fitch{\neg\square\neg q}{\Diamond q\hspace{10ex}\Diamond\text{Def}\\
\bot\hspace{11ex}\bot\text{In}}\\\square\neg q\hspace{13.5ex}\text{IP}\\
\fitch{\square}
{\neg p\hspace{10.2ex}\square\text{Out}\\
\neg q\hspace{10.2ex}\square\text{Out}\\
\fitch{p\lor q}{\fitch{p}{\bot}\fitch{q}{\bot}\\\bot\hspace{7ex}\lor\text{Out}}\\\neg(p\lor q)\hspace{5ex}\text{IP}}
\\\square\neg(p\lor q)\hspace{6.5ex}\square\text{In}\\
\bot\hspace{14.8ex}\bot\text{In}}\\
\Diamond p\lor\Diamond q\hspace{12.4ex}\text{IP}}
\end{align}

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwww Thank you so much. I was struggling on this. Thank you! Thanks!