# Garson Exercise 2.4(a), Show axiom (4) is provable in S5

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, modal-logic

$\lozenge $= possible

$\square $=necessary

Hey all, I am trying to show the following axiom is provable in $S5$:

$\square A \to \square \square A = (4)$

The hint says to prove: $\square A \to \square \lozenge \square A $ first, which I have done:

1 ) $\square A$

2-) $\square \lnot \square A \to \lnot \square A$         (instance M)

3-) $\square A$  (1, Reit)

4-) $\lnot \lnot \square A$                        (3, ~~In)

5-) $\lnot \square \lnot \square A$                    (2-4, MT)

6-) $\lozenge \square A$                          (5, Def $\lozenge$)

7-) $\lozenge \square A \to \square \lozenge \square A$         (instance of 5: $\lozenge P \to \square \lozenge P$)

8-) $\square \lozenge \square A$   (6-7, MP)

9 ) $\square A \to \square \lozenge \square A$  (1-8, CP)

I am stuck on the second leg, any help on how to prove $ \square \lozenge \square A \to \square \square A$

By the way, there is a similar question here but it is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a Natural deduction. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to put it in the math form on this website.

Comment: See the way someone has formatted [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742151/diamond-distribution-in-system-k-garson-modal-logic-exercise-1-8)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry. I saw that. I don't understand the edit. Its too much it says array and stuff. I found this $\square and \diamond$ i will put it.

Comment: What about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574752/proving-box-a-rightarrow-box-box-a-from-kg-r) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry i think that's axiomatic i haven't learned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
In Exercise $2.3 (i)$ you should already proved, or you need to attempt this first

direction $1$
$\fitch{\Diamond\square A}
{\vdots\\\square A}\hspace{5ex}\text{direction $2$}\fitch{\square A}
{\vdots\\\Diamond\square A}$

Exercise $2.4(a)$ will become much easier

$\fitch{\square A}
{\Diamond\square A\hspace{10ex}\text{$2.3(i)$ direction 2}\\
\square\Diamond\square A\hspace{8ex} (5)\\
\fitch{\square}
{\Diamond\square A\hspace{6.5ex}\square\text{Out}\\
\square A\hspace{8ex}\text{$2.3(i)$ direction 1}}\\
\square\square A\hspace{10ex}\square\text{In}}$

Update:

If not sure about how to prove $2.3i)$ check this

$\color{lightgrey}{\fitch{\color{black}{\square A}}
{\color{black}{\Diamond\square A\hspace{16ex}\text{$2.1(a)$}}\\
\square\Diamond\square A\hspace{14ex} (5)\\
\fitch{\square}
{\color{black}{\Diamond\square A\hspace{11.5ex}\square\text{Out}\\
\neg\square\neg\square A\hspace{7.5ex}\Diamond\text{Def}\\
\fitch{\neg\square A}{\Diamond\neg A\hspace{9.2ex}\text{1.10(b)}\\
\square\Diamond\neg A\hspace{7ex}(5)\\
\fitch{\square}
{\Diamond\neg A\hspace{5.6ex}\square\text{Out}\\
\neg\square\neg\neg A\hspace{2.2ex}\Diamond\text{Def}}\\
\square\neg\square\neg\neg A\hspace{4ex}\square\text{In}\\
\square\neg\square A\hspace{6.8ex}\text{2.3(g)}\\
\bot\hspace{12.2ex}\bot\text{In}
}}\\
\color{black}{\square A\hspace{13.8ex}\text{IP}}}\\
\square\square A\hspace{15.5ex}\square\text{In}
}}$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: i have one question, in 2.3(i) i introduced a variant of axiom (5): $\diamond \lnot A \rightarrow \square \diamond \lnot A$ to make the derivation easy. Can i introduce an iteration of the axiom inside a boxed sub-proof? like this:

Comment: 1) $\square $ {

2) $\diamond \square A$ (box out)

3) $\diamond \lnot A \rightarrow \square \diamond \lnot A$ (instance of 5)}

Comment: you can introduce it by assume $\Diamond\neg A$ apply $(5)$ get $\square\Diamond\neg A$, and by CP we get $\Diamond\neg A\to\square\Diamond\neg A$, but to use it you don't have to write it in this way.

Comment: @ryan If still not sure about $2.3(i)$, you can check the update

Comment: Thank you, my derivation was slightly different from your I didn't have to use 2.3g, but I think it would be best to utilize this derivation instead since mine could be wrong.

Comment: Can you answer this please?  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/75572/47053